# How to get offset top of td element relative parent tr element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following dummy html markup:

```
<table>
    <body>
       <tr>
         <td id="cell" style="height: 1000px; width: 200px;"></td>
       </tr>
    </body>
</table>
```

I need to subscribe to click event on cell and get top offset relative parent table row (tr).

```
jQuery('#cell', function (e) {
       // get top offset in pixels relative parent tr element
});
```

What's the best way?

**Edit:** I mean I need to get mouse click offset relative tr element

Comment: Not sure what that code is supposed to do, but `$('#cell').position().top` should get you what you want.

Comment: I mean I need to get mouse click offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I correctly understood your question, this code should do the trick. It just outputs the x,y mouse coords relative to the cell container. The output alert is triggered by a mouse click on the cell.

```
o = $("#cell");
o.click(
    function (e) {        
        offsetX = e.pageX - o.position().left;
        offsetY = e.pageY - o.position().top;
        alert('offsetX: ' + offsetX + '\noffsetY:' + offsetY);
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dcudb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Probably this..?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<style>
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}
table tr{width:200px;float:left;background-color:red;position:relative;}
table tr td{width:100px;background-color:red;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //if you want offset from tr
  $('td').click(function(){
       var leftParent=$(this).parent('tr').offset().left
       var topParent=$(this).parent('tr').offset().top
       var left=Math.round(($(this).offset().left)-leftParent);
       var top=Math.round(($(this).offset().top)-topParent)
       alert('top'+top+' left'+left)
      })
    //if you want offset from table  
  $('td').click(function(){
       var leftParent=$(this).parents('table').position().left
       var topParent=$(this).parents('table').position().top
       var left=Math.round(($(this).offset().left)-leftParent);
       var top=Math.round(($(this).offset().top)-topParent)
       alert('top'+top+' left'+left)
      })          

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">aaa</td>
        <td class="cell">bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">ccc</td>
        <td class="cell">ddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell">eee</td>
        <td class="cell">fff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```